# No /etc/motd/ ubuntu. Where is it?

Tags: ssh

I was trying to edit the motd when I ssh into my Ubtunu computer, but can't /etc/motd anywhere on my system.

```
kiancross@whb:/$ cd /etc/motd
-bash: cd: /etc/motd: No such file or directory
```

This is probably something very stupid that I am doing, but can't find anything anywhere. Is the motd file only for server version of ubuntu? Any answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: On my Ubuntu system `/etc/motd` is a symlink to `/var/run/motd` but I don't get the same error if I try to `cd /etc/motd`.

Comment: My Ubuntu 14.10 has a number of scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/`, but that is the only instance of `motd` in any file name in the `/etc/` directory. What do you want to do? It should be fairly simple to write your own script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/motd` isn't a directory, it is a plain file (or a symbolic link to a plain file).

Hence you can't `cd` in it, but you can edit it:

```
vi /etc/motd
```

or:

```
echo 'Hello world!' >/etc/motd
```